# Sorting split variables from an array in a Perl script into this specific format?

Tags: perl, loops, unix, scripting, sybase

I have wrote a script that calls another script using two arguments where one is a log file and the other is a sql file, what i'm trying to capture is a spid and a cid (two entries) from the database, i have managed to capture the output into an array. for example 325 is a spid & p58 is a cid.

```
325    p58
525    p58
591    p58
1180   p85
```

but i am supposed to arrange it in a specific format where there can't be any repeated cids and each cid should have its spids printed next to it. I have managed to split the array and this is what i could come up with so far

```
p58- 325
p58- 525
p58- 591
p58- 1180
```

and here's the required format.

p58- 325, 525, 591, 1180

```
    my @results = capture( [0,1,2], $^X, "/asp_batch/bin/clientquery.pl", @ARGV);


    my $size =  scalar(@results);


    for (my $count = 0; $count < $size; $count++)
      {
         my ($spid, $cid) = split /\s+/, $results[$count];
         print $cid, "- ";
         print $spid, "\n";

      }
```

Comment: We could really do with some sample input as plain text, and desired output in the question - we don't really like links to images, because it makes replicating the data for testing purposes a lot harder (e.g. hidden characters, etc.)

But we also don't know what a 'spid' and ' cid' is, so we have to sort of guess based on what what you've put in place.

Comment: i have took out the link to the images and got them listed down instead, can you check it out. Also the cid and the spid are two types of entries in a database, cid is the client id and each client id can have multiple spids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hash to collect the values indexed on the `cid`. Once you've collected everything, output one line per key in the hash:

```
my %hash;

for (my $count = 0; $count < $size; $count++)
      {
         my ($spid, $cid) = split /\s+/, $results[$count];
         # the hash value is an anonymous array
         # it's created automatically for you when
         # you treat the value as a reference
         push @{ $hash{$cid} }, $spid;

      }  

foreach my $cid ( sort keys %hash ) 
    {
      say "$cid- ", join " ", @{ $hash{$cid} };
    }
```

This is a very common Perl technique. Most of the times when "only once" or "unique" show up in the problem, someone is going to reach for a hash.

Comment: I'm hesitant to correct the man that literally wrote the book on it, but surely `foreach @results` would be a much more elegant way to iterate?

Comment: I merely took the for loop from the question without thinking much about it. I typically don't care to push style on StackOverflow so I don't distract from the main point. Barraging people with all sorts of other things they didn't ask tends to make us look shrill.